# not working converting date factor to datetime

Tags: r, datetime

I imported txt file that has date in it and is has this format 1/25/2019 2:15:19 PM. How do I convert it to numeric date as 1-25-2019 2:15:19

I used

```
transform(date_loaded=as.POSIXct(date_loaded, format="%d/%m/%Y T %H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: `lubridate` should make this easy `dmy_hms`

Comment: Thanks lubridate work perfectly, I changed the dmy_hms to mdy_hms

Answer (score 0):

Use `%I` for the hour and `%p` for the AM/PM as shown.  This is vectorized and no packages are used.

```
as.POSIXct(factor("1/25/2019 2:15:19 PM"), format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
## [1] "2019-01-25 14:15:19 EST"
```

See `?strptime` for more information.